# Proving a simple modulo equality

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm probably lacking some basic concept here but I'm trying to prove that

$$ ((a \mod k) \cdot k + b) \mod k = (a \cdot k + b) \mod k$$

I get stuck at the passage where, applying [distributive formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalencies), I get

$$ a \cdot k \mod k = ((a \mod k) \cdot (k \mod k)) \mod k$$

since $k \mod k$ is zero.

Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation $a \mod k = r$.

Then $a = ka_1 + r$ and:
$$
((a \mod k) \cdot k + b) \mod k = ((a-k \cdot a_1) \cdot k + b) \mod k \\= (a\cdot k + b -k \cdot a1 \cdot k) \mod k = (a \cdot k + b) \mod k
$$
The last equality is from the fact that $a \mod k = (a + nk) \mod k, \forall n$

Comment: Thanks Eugen! You solved my problem!

Comment: @Dean You welcome